# How to store high resolution image data in unsigned char* in C++ optimally?

Tags: c++, c, image, image-processing

I'm learning image processing. Right now, I've a function which has a parameter unsigned char* which is basically taking the image information. This function block works fine with low resolution images but for high resolution images it's very slow, probably because unsigned char* is huge. I think I can decompose my image into many blocks and process them individually, but the problem is that I may need information from other blocks as well while working on a given block.

Any help on how to approach this problem is appreciated.

Comment: You could provide definitions of what you mean by "high resolution" and "huge", and the contents of the relevant function. Data representation and algorithm need to be considered together.

Comment: By high resolution I mean more number of pixels which increases size of unsigned char* used for representing image. I can't post the function block. I will try to explain what it does. It is making a fine selection of some portion image based on the stroke made using mouse. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the image is not in a suitable format for memory processing.

A suitable format would be divisible, i.e. you can load a part of it and still be able to wok on that without requiring bits from other parts. I would suggest converting the image to another format, and then do as you suggest, processing it piece by piece.

If you really need other image parts while processing, you need to either rethink your algorithm or choose your subdivision in a smart way.

Comment: Thanks rubenvb. I might need to re-think.